# Will an arraylist be empty after adding the object to another arraylist

Tags: arrays

```
public void enqueue(Packet...packets)
{  
   ArrayList<Packet>type1 = new ArrayList();
   ArrayList<Packet>type2 = new ArrayList();
   boolean t = true;


   for(Packet packet : packets)
   {
       if(packet.getClassType() == t )
       {
           type1.add(packet);
       }   
       else
       {
           type2.add(packet);
       }        
   } 


   if(queue.isEmpty())
   {
       if(type1.isEmpty())
       {
       //DO NOTHING
       }
       else
       {
       queue.addAll(type1);
       }
       if(type2.isEmpty())
       {
       //DO NOTHING
       }
       else
       {
       queue.addAll(type2);  
       }
   } 
   else
   {

       for(int i = 1 ; i<=queue.size() ; i++ )
       {
           if (queue.get(i).getClassType() != t)
           {
               if(type1.isEmpty())
               {
                   // DO NOTHING
               }
               else
               {
               queue.addAll(i, type1);
               }
           }
       }
       if(type2.isEmpty())
       {
        // DO NOTHING
       }
       else
       {
       queue.addAll(type2);
       }
   } 
}
```

in this code I get an ArrayList of Packets that have classtype true or fase. In a first stage, i sort these Packets based on their classtype. After this, i add these new Arraylists (type 1 and type 2) in a specific way to another arraylist 'queue'. 
I am wondering if, after this code has been executed, the arraylists type 1 and type 2 are empty again, or should i add a function in my code to remove the Packets after they have been stored in the queue ArrayList ?

kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the contents of your ArrayList to another ArrayList, you are copying the data from the first to the second. So no, when you do this you are not "emptying" the content from one list into another. That means that your original data is still present in the `type1` and `type2` ArrayLists, and it is now present in your new ArrayList as well. So if you want to reuse your `type1` and `type2` ArrayLists, the easy way would be to simply reinitialize them, which will overwrite the reference with a new (empty) ArrayList object. You would do it like this...

```
type1 = new ArrayList<>();
type2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response ! Is this not what I'm doing in the first lines of my function ? If i would use this function in a loop, and let it execute 100 times, would the type1 and type2 not be empty at the start of every loop ?